# ng-repeat on adjacent list or infinite nested list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm creating a repeating list of headings which can have an infinite amount of nested headers. The test data I have is as follows:

[image]

Using ng-repeat I'm trying to get a form to look like this:

```
1 - Background
2 - Legal Requirements
2.1 - State Legal Requirements
2.1.1 - Regulations
4 - Quiz
3 - Site Security
```

I come up with the code JSFiddle When I run it I get an infinite loop. Appreciate if I can get assistance on how to get the above results, thanks in advance!

My JsFiddle. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/8d756znn/15/)

Comment: Is there any chance you have a circular reference?

Comment: I guess so, I'm working jsfiddle which I will share shortly

Comment: just add my jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the following two key steps:

1. Process the data in the controller to create a nested, recursive data structure.
2. Use a recursive `ng-include` to render this nested structure

Here is the markup:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="listFn()">Generate list</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="heading in headings" ng-include="'subheader'"></li>
    </ul>      
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="subheader">
    <span class="number">{{heading.id}}</span>
    <span class="heading">{{heading.text}}</span>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="heading in heading.children" ng-include="'subheader'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

And here is the controller code. Note that I used the powerful [Lodash](http://lodash.com) library to make this easier:

```
function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        head_id: 'Background',
        parent_head_id: 0,
        sort_order: 1
    },
    // ... more here ...
    {
        head_id: 'State Legal Requirements',
        parent_head_id: 'Legal Requirements',
        sort_order: 1
    }]
    $scope.listFn = function () {
        var byParentHeadId = _.groupBy($scope.data, 'parent_head_id');

        function headingLevel(parent_head_id, levelPrefix) {
            return _.chain(byParentHeadId[parent_head_id])
                .sortBy('sort_order')
                .map(function (heading, index) {
                    var id = levelPrefix ? levelPrefix + '.' + (index + 1) : '' + (index + 1);
                    return {
                        id: id,
                        text: heading.head_id,
                        children: headingLevel(heading.head_id, id)
                    };
                })
                .value();
        }

        $scope.headings = headingLevel(0, '');
    }
}
```

You can see it in action [in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxs2utex/1/).